# How to check JTextField text to String?

Tags: java, string, project, boolean, jtextfield

I have a problem on checking the text and string.

```
public boolean Isequals(Object c){
    boolean check = false;
    if (c instanceof MyTextTwist){
        MyTextTwist tt = (MyTextTwist)c;
    if (txtGuessPad.getText().equals(answer))
        check = true;}
    return check;
    }
```

this what i have so far.

Comment: what is txtGuessPad? and what is MyTextTwist?

Comment: By reading this question, you may feel like you're reading an ancient egyption wall or something..from my experience in such things I guess the question is about Comparing The JTextField contents with another string.

Comment: Error when i click the submit button? do i have to use the txtGuesspad.getText().equals(answer)?

Comment: @M.H that what it is. Sorry but im not very good in english :(

Comment: @HilverBomb The problem is not about your english, but you must explain more details so we can help you. What is "MyTextTwist"?? What is "answer" ? and What is The error...etc

Comment: The answer contains the word which is i want to compare with the word input by the user, Im creating a texttwist and the MyTextTwist is my constructor. the error is when i click the submit button it doesn't do anything

Comment: What are you expecting from the submit button to do ? your "if" condition seems to be correct.Also is there a compiler error in your code ?

Comment: if the the text and the answer is the same i want it to return true. i just wondering if the gettext().equals is correct?

Comment: @HilverBomb Yes it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is not very clear, i suggest these answers:

1st option - you want to get string from your JTextField:

```
String text = txtGuessPad.getText();
```

2nd option - you want to check if text contains only letter:

```
String text = txtGuessPad.getText();
if(text.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$")){...
```

3rd option - you want to compare two strings (one of them is from JTextField):

```
String text = txtGuessPad.getText();
String text2 = "test";
if(text.equals(text2)){... //if you want to match whole word and case sensitive
if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(text2)){... //if you want to match whole word and NOT case sensitive
if(text.startsWith(text2)){... //if you want to check if you string starts with other string
```

4th option - let's put it in a function:

```
public boolean isEqualToString(JTextField textField, String compareTo) {
     String text = textField.getText();
     if(text.equals(compareTo)) {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: public class SubmitHandler implements ActionListener{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  String text = txtGuessPad.getText();
  String text2 = answer;
  int score = 10;
  if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(text2)){
   txtscore.setText(score);}//error here :(
   }
}